# How to implement IEnumerable<int> from this c# code?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to convert this c# code into c++/cli code:

```
class MyRange : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { return null; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return null; }
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
namespace Tests {
    public ref class MyRange : System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<int> {
    private:
        virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetEnumerator() = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator {
            return nullptr;
        }

        virtual System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<int>^ GetEnumerator() {
            return nullptr;
        }
    };
}
```

It's giving me so many errors (like 20), that I don't even think it's worth putting them here.

I've googled it all and it seems like a lot of people are having the same problem as me.

Comment: You could try compiling it and running it through Reflector, then switching the language. Out of curiousity, what's the business case for moving from C# to C++?

Comment: I tried it. The reflector's result don't work :(

Comment: As C++/CLI don't support yield return, I need to manually implement IEnumerable/IEnumerator. I'm not moving from c# to c++/cli, I am just doing some interop with c++/cli to see how it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of fighting found some working code:

```
namespace Tests {
    ref class MyCollection : public Generic::IEnumerable<int>
    {
    public:
        virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetEnumeratorNonGeneric() = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        virtual Generic::IEnumerator<int>^ MyCollection::GetEnumerator()
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's often helpful to disassemble your C# in Reflector using Managed C++ as the target language and then from there do the translation to C++/CLI.